# magento - default theme with 1px more at webkit

Tags: css, magento, webkit, themes

Magento (ver. 1.6.0.0) default frontend theme / skin,

In Chrome 14.0 / Safari 5.1 [Win7 32x] there is 1px of white space, 
[image: Chrome]

In Firefox, Opera and IE looks fine.

[image: Firefox]

Of curse you can see it for your self at http://demo.magentocommerce.com/

Very frustrating, I'm trying to solve the problem. As I see...

```
/* skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css, line 100 */

.main { 
   width:900px; 
   margin:0 auto; 
   min-height:400px; 
   padding:25px 25px 80px; 
   background:#fffffe url(../images/bkg_main2.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; 
   text-align:left; 
}
```

`.main` div is 950px wide.

`bkg_main2.gif` is 962px wide and 653px high, but it has 6px shadow at left and right side, blank space in center is 950px wide.

So, everything should be fine.

Any idea where is the problem ?!
Thank you for any good thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.main { background: url("../images/bkg_main2.gif") no-repeat scroll -1px 0 #FFFFFE; }
}
```

That should correct the background alignment on all webkit browsers. Let me know how it goes